# How to do the Automation of Rest API With Bearer Token Authentication and Authorization?

Tags: rest, selenium, automation

I am Trying to Automate the Rest API with Rest Assured and i am doing the Scenario which has Bearer Token Authentication first and Then need to do the Authorization of another URL

I have Tried the Below Code

```
     public class Authentication {

        @BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();
    RestAssured.authentication =
                  preemptive().basic("username", "password");

 }
@Test
public void successfulTest() {
    String bearerToken = null;
    URI url = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Response response =given.headers  
                               ("Authorization", "Bearer "   +                                                                                              bearerToken, "Content-                      Type",ContentType.JSON,"Accept",           ContentType.JSON)
            .when()
            .get(url)
            .then()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .extract()
            .response();
}
```

}